# Convert 2 + 5 +8+ . . . + (6n-1) = n(6n+1) to Sigma Notation

Tags: summation

***2** + **5** + **8** + . . . + **(6n-1)** = **n(6n+1**)*

This is what I have so far.

The **sum** of **(3j-1)** from **j=1** to *something I`m not sure of*.

Comment: $3j-1=6n-1$ so $j$ is ?

Comment: Note that the equation is incorrect: the actual sum of the terms on the lefthand side is $n(6n+1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n} (3i-1) = n(6n+1)$$

This will give you as terms of the series: \begin{align*}3(1)-1&=2\\3(2)-1&=5\\\ldots\\3(2n)-1&=6n-1\end{align*}

EDIT: the problem statement purported that $\sum_{i=1}^{2n} (3i-1) = n(6n-1)$. I will just prove below that this is wrong, and $\sum_{i=1}^{2n} (3i-1) = n(6n+1)$.

\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n} (3i-1) &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n} 3i + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n}-1
\\ &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n} 3i + (-2n)
\\ &= 3\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n} i + (-2n)
\end{align*}
Then we just use the summation formula: $\sum_{i=1}^{N}i = \frac{N(N+1)}{2}$.
\begin{align*}
\\ 3\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n} i + (-2n) &= 3\left( \frac{2n(2n+1)}{2}\right) + (-2n)
\\ &= 3n(2n+1)-2n
\\ &= 6n^2+3n-2n
\\ &= 6n^2+n
\\ &= n(6n+1)
\end{align*}

Comment: why is it 2n instead of just n ...

Comment: @user114027 look at the edited post.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @user114027 Sure. You're Welcome. I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: You might want to add that the equation as given in the problem is incorrect: the righthand side should be $n(6n+1)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Indeed. The sum equates to n(6n+1) and not n(6n-1). Good catch.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott fixed, with a proof.

Comment: @user114027 I've also proven the fact that it adds to $n(6n+1)$. You may find this useful.

Comment: Looks good. (I’d already upvoted.) You could also simply use the formula for the sum of an arithmetic series: there are $2n$ terms, the first and last being $2$ and $6n-1$, so the sum is $$\frac{2n(2+(6n-1))}2=n(6n+1)\;,$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh, that didn't occur to me. I didn't even know that formula. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Could it just be:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{2n} (3j-1)\;?$$

We test this by letting $n=3$.  Then, we see that:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{6} (3j-1) = 2 + 5 +8+11+14+17=57 = (3)[(6)(3)-1]=n(6n+1)$$

Comment: No, that can't be it; that evaluates to $n(6n+1)$, not $n(6n-1)$.

Comment: Why is it not just n...

Comment: Well it can't be just $n$ because then the final term of the sum would be $(3n-1)$, not $(6n-1)$, as the problem indicates.  Would it not?

Comment: @bof: That error seems to be present in the original problem statement.

Comment: @NathanTowle Oh yah. It sure wouldn`t be just n.